# react native remove white space around a picture

Tags: react-native, contains, image-cropper

Hi I desperately need a help in solving this issue.

Currently image is contained in react native and we are using a slider for product image.
When we upload a product image, it adds white spaces around the picture uploaded and we really want to remove the white space..

If someone knows how to solve this issue, please help us.

the attached image shows the red space represents a product picture... all we wanna do is to remove the white space on the sides of the picture...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cM9IK.jpg)

Comment: Please provide your code, your minimal working example with the container in which you embedd the image. This seems like we just need to remove some padding properties.

Comment: may its because of padding,
u can  set padding:0px;

Answer (score 1):

Set your image width and height to be '100%' of your parent View. And for View set fixed width and height, and remove the padding. It should work.